# Как сделать кросс-компиляцию 32-х битного приложения в 64-х битное?

Tags: c++, borland, кросс-компиляция

Имеется небольшое 32-х битное приложение, написанное в среде Borland C++ Builder 6. Какой удобнее и проще всего применить компилятор, чтобы он сгенерировал 64-х битный код?

Comment: А какой смысл в таких манипуляциях? 32-х битные приложения работают на 64-х битных системах. Если используются стандартные функции Win32 API, то портировать в Visual Studio и там играться с настройками.

Comment: Смысл в назначении. Это загрузчик программы, имеющей две отдельные версии: 32-х и 64-х битную. В 32-х битном загрузчике с 64-х битной программой не работают функции, имеющие адресацию, например, WriteProcessMemory или VirtualProtect, всё остальное работает. Для решения проблемы Вы предлагаете освоить Visual Studio и там играться. А проще варианта нет?

Comment: У нынешнего билдера есть [версия посвежее](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/64-bit_Windows_Application_Development).

Comment: Пока мучаю RAD Studio 10.2 в Win7 x64. При инсталляции: Additional Platform Support > Windows 64-bit > Will be installed... В папке есть ...\bin64, но исполняемого файла там нет, он есть только в \bin. В главном окне в окошке выбора конфигурации есть только 32-bit Windows. Но в Tools > Options > C++ Options > Paths and Directories есть окошко Selected Platform, где можно выбрать 64-bit Windows. Старый проект (Builder 6) компилирует без ошибок, но выдаёт кучу одинаковых Warning, говорящих о непонимании 64-х битной адресации. Как установить настройки RAD, чтобы она генерировала 64-х битный код?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос есть [в статье Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/64-bit_Windows_Hello_World_Application_(Delphi_and_C%2B%2B)#Create_and_configure_a_console_application_for_the_64-bit_Windows_target). Спасибо всем, кто проявил интерес.